# Access to private files change after deleting parent node where it was originally attached

Tags: files

I just ran into a situation where access to private files changed after its deleting parent node.  I confirmed that anonymous users *do not* have "View private files" permission. If the node is *unpublished*, access to the file is denied. If the node is *deleted*, then access is granted to file by anonymous users.

It looks like this has been addressed in the past, but after reading (and re-reading) the issues below, I couldn't identify if this is a bug that needs to be re-examined in 8.4 or if things are working as designed and I'm soliciting feedback as a result.

The file_entity module is also in-play on the site and the following issue may be particularly salient.

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2892628

See also:

> "Private files that are no longer attached to an entity should not suddenly become accessible to people who couldn't see them before"

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2461845

Comment: Other related issues include https://www.drupal.org/node/1816584 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1414990